# How to use this buddypress function "bppp_progression_block($user_id)" outside a member's profile page

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I'm creating a wordpress widget based on buddypress 2.0. This widget will simply output displayed user's progress bar and percentage in a side bar.

I've already written the main code for the widget and I'm using this function `bppp_progression_block($user_id)` to output the progress bar in a side bar. The function is from another plugin called buddypress-profile-progression. The function is defined in this plugin.

How can I make that function work outside a member's profile page?

Here is the main code for my wordpress widget:

```
$user_id = bp_loggedin_user_id(); // Get the logged in user's id
echo bppp_get_progression_block($user_id); // Output the progress bar
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a BuddyPress function, but BuddyPress Profile Progression plugin. So it's better to ask that plugin author. Its support is here: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/buddypress-profile-progression

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

In bppp-template.php change lines 50-52 from:

```
     $user_id = bp_displayed_user_id($user_id);
     if(!$user_id) return false;
```

to:

```
     $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
     $user_id = $current_user->ID;
```

On line 67 change:

```
$user_id = bppp_get_user_id($user_id);
```

to:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id = $current_user->ID;
```

On lines 71-73 change:

```
if(bp_is_my_profile()){
    $title = '<a title="'.bppp_get_caption($user_id).'" href="'.bppp_get_link($user_id).'">'.$title.'</a>';
}
```

to just:

```
$title = '<a title="'.bppp_get_caption($user_id).'" href="'.bppp_get_link($user_id).'">'.$title.'</a>';
```

Change 118 from:

```
 $user_id = bppp_get_user_id($user_id);
```

to:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
     $user_id = $current_user->ID;
```